# Facebook In App web browser clears my browser cookies after 2-3 days

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I have articles which are posted on Facebook for our subscribers and when a user clicks in one of the links they get re-directed to a mobile-site where they login, the problem is now after a a few days 2-3 days the mobile site asks them to authenticate again.

Im guessing Facebook in app browser clears my cookies but what i need to know is how does it manage its cookies especially for external sites. I tried the Facebook developer website there's no documentation on how this in app webview/browser works.

Answer (score 2):

**Background Info**

Facebook in app browser is rather  a webview which renders all the links which user's browse so instead of delegating the rendering to an external browser it handles everything on its own. This comes with limited functionality  of course,  Facebook added this in app browsing functionality to keep user's in session, because most of the time if user's make use of external browsers they don't come back into the app.
With the above background information Facebook browser is accessible to developer's in a sense that they may choose to use Deep-Linking if the browser doesn't  conform to their specifications because the browser is closed i.e you can not modify  or rather interact with it, thats why the deep linking functionality allows for developers  to give user's an option to choose wether they wish to use their app this is if they have it installed in their mobile devices.

**Cookies**

Cookie management entirely depends on the In-app browser which if a user wishes to clear them then they can do so via their  app settings. Since Facebook in-app browser manages its own cookies thus if a webpage is rendered by the in-app browser it will entirely depend of the in-app browser if its time to clear them from the device.

**Deep Linking Overview**

App Links is an open standard to deep link to content in your app. When someone using your app shares content to Facebook or another App Links-enabled app you can create a link that makes it possible to jump back into your app from that piece of content.
App Links work by adding metadata to existing URLs on the web so that they can be consumed by your app. If your app doesn't have a web presence with content you can annotate, you can also use a Facebook-provided service to host the data.
The Facebook's app for iOS and Android support App Links today. When the Facebook app comes across a link that supports App Links it will launch your app with the right information so someone can see the content immediately and quickly.

**How App Linking Works**

1. A person clicks on a story on Facebook
   If someone shares a story on Facebook with content from your app, people can click on the story to view the content in your app. The URL shared to Facebook contains App Link metadata or be a Facebook-hosted URL.
2. Facebook app looks up the URL to see if it supports App Links
   Once someone clicks on a story, the Facebook App does a lookup to see if the content supports App Links. if it does, the Facebook App takes people to your content, either in a web view or by launching your app and linking to the content, depending on the following criteria:
   Whether people have your app installed
   Whether the device is and Android or iOS device
   Whether your app is mobile only
   App Links has the following requirements:
   If the content is a web page, your web page must include markup to let the app know what app should be launched.
   If the content is mobile only, you must still supply a valid http(s) URL that hosts the App Link metadata. Facebook provides a Hosting API for App Links to make it easy for app developers to support App Links content without having to set up a web server.
   In order to accept incoming App Links, your app will need to be set up to support them. We cover how to do that for both iOS and Android.

**Launching Outbound Apps**

It's possible for any app to do what the Facebook app does and add support to launch other apps based on App Links. If you've got an app where people want to click through to links instead of just going to inbound links, we've also provided a document that covers how to add support for the outbound navigation protocolto your app.